# Oracle - PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when try to create JOB

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

i have a problem here,
i already have a Stored Procedure called "SP_DEL_TOKEN"
and i wanna make a job to run the Stored procedure automatically everyday..

this is my script to make the job

```
VAR jobno NUMBER;
BEGIN
DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(:jobno, 'SP_DEL_TOKEN', SYSDATE, 'SYSDATE+1');
COMMIT;
END;
/
```

but when i do that script, i encountered with this error

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 106:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:
:= . ( @ % ;
The symbol ";" was substituted for "END" to continue.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_JOB", line 79
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_JOB", line 136
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

please help me,
and thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 1):

You need a semicolon at the end of the "what" parameter.  Use `'SP_DEL_TOKEN;'` instead of `'SP_DEL_TOKEN'`.  See the manual for [some more examples](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23448/d_job.htm#sthref4936).

I'm not sure why this is.  With dynamic SQL you cannot have a semicolon, and with dynamic PL/SQL you need the `BEGIN` and `END;`.  I guess this parameter is used in some weird context.