# Oracle PL/SQL Trigger: Reset column value automatically after an update statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle12c

For testing purpose I would like to have the following scenario to be automated:

1. Set column **Status** of my table to the value **closed** (using an update statement)
2. Commit the update so that other user can be seeing new value of **Status**
3. Wait for 1 minutes
4. Reset column **Status** of my table to its original value **init** (using a trigger)
5. Commit the update so that other user can be seeing the original value of **Status**

I've tried using this trigger but it won't work and I got

> ORA-04091: table name is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER RESET_COLUMN
AFTER UPDATE OF STATUS ON MY_TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.STATUS != 'INIT')
BEGIN
    DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(60);  
    UPDATE MY_TABLE SET STATUS = 'INIT';
    COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Since it is not allowed to commit inside a trigger, is there any other approach to solve this problem? Using a job based on event?

Comment: `:new.status := 'INIT';` And remove the `commit` from the trigger. You can't have any transaction handling inside a trigger

Comment: But I need to commit these transactions so that they are available for other users. Please see the edited questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run this as a job you need a procedure you can call. I presume you want to do this for a specific record not the whole table, hence the ID parameter.

```
create or replace procedure reset_my_table_status
    ( p_id in number )
is
begin 
    update my_table
    set status = 'INIT'
    where id = p_id;
    commit;
end;
/
```

Then, from your trigger submit a job to call that procedure after sixty seconds:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER RESET_COLUMN
AFTER UPDATE OF STATUS ON MY_TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.STATUS != 'INIT')
DECLARE
    jn number;
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
BEGIN
    dbms_job.submit(jn 
                   , what=>'reset_my_table_status('||:new.id||');'
                   , next_date => sysdate + 60/86400
      );
    commit;
END;
/
```

Setting the `next_date` parameter means the job will trigger in sixty seconds, so no need for the  `sleep()` call. Remember, for jobs to run you need JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES init parameter to have value > 0. We have to commit to submit a job; so we need to have an autonomous transaction because normally we cannot issue commits from triggers.

Alternatively, you could just build a procedure (or even an anonymous block).

```
create or replace procedure my_table_status_test
    ( p_id in number )
is
begin 
    update my_table
    set status = 'MEH'
    where id = p_id;
    commit;

    DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(60);  

    update my_table
    set status = 'INIT'
    where id = p_id;
    commit;
end;
/
```

Then just run the procedure for whatever ID you want to test.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked as expected but I needed to add a semicolon in `what=>'reset_my_table_status('||:new.id||');'` otherwise I'll get Oracle - PLS-00103. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023625/oracle-pls-00103-encountered-the-symbol-end-when-try-to-create-job

Comment: Ooops. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like such a bad idea.  `sleep()` inside of a trigger?  That will just compound locks and tie up resources.

Instead, you can use a view or virtual columns.  Store the `closeDate` as a column in the table (you can use a trigger to set this if you like).

```
alter table my_table
    add new_status as (case when closeDate > sysdate - 1 / (24*60) then 'closed' else status end);
```

Comment: Thanks but modifying the table structure is not an option in my case.

Comment: @nogc . . . a view is not a modification to the table structure (virtual columns are, but not a view).